# Should you mention security exploits that you've discovered on a resume?

Tags: resume, software-industry, career-development, careers

I'm sure I'm not the only soon-to-be graduate who is pondering on this question. Would it be a good idea to put exploits that I have found on a web application, programs, etc on my resume?

Would it be good to add it if you helped to solve them? I'm asking this with the intention to find out if it's good for Software Development jobs.

Comment: As a non-developer, I'm a bit confused as to what the question is because 'exploits' aren't really clearly defined. Is this something obvious to anyone working in software (what the extent of an exploit is), or would the answer differ depending on the type of exploit? (assuming what an exploit is, I think there would be a big difference between finding a way to use zalgo text on Stack Overflow to break their layout, and finding a way to transfer funds to your account on a banking site). If this is all common-sense stuff that people understand, that's cool, but if not, could you make an [edit]?

Comment: I don't want to make this question specifically about my case which is why I left it ambiguous. In my specific case, it's regarding the Fifa Ultimate team Web app. I found some bugs in EA's software(some that cheat the game) and reported it to EA with code. Was wondering if that would be a good thing to add on a resume.

Comment: If it's about gaming specifically, [this question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11750/) may give some helpful advice (although not an exact duplicate).

Comment: You should make this question specifically about you. Others will review your question, and decide for themselves whether your issue is scalable to them. The result of questions that point in all directions is answers that point in all directions. If that happens, then the answers are no good to anyone including you.

Answer (score 8):

> Would it be a good idea to put exploits that I have found on a web
>   application, programs, etc on my resume?

Yes! Absolutely. There is nothing more a company wants than to hire a “white hat” hacker who actually understands the concepts of security, how to test for flaws & how to quantify flaws.

You really have no idea how many parochial techs there are in the I.T. world who simply robotically follow a bullet list of items & don’t but really thought into what they are doing.

Showing you are inquisitive, skilled & adaptive in the tech world will knock you to the top of any hiring list.

Answer (score 3):

It's a good idea.

Generally the rule is 'tailor your CV to the job'. Meaning that you highlight any accomplishments and skills that make you a good fit for the job that needs to be done.

However, for a graduate you can be a bit more general - the employer appreciates that you don't have work experience, and are more looking to see that overall - you're motivated, on to it, can learn on the job, and are going to be good cultural fit. On this theme, that you've discovered exploits demonstrates that you go above and beyond.

With exploits - yes, there's the concern that the potential employer is going to think, 'Exploits?! This guy is going to be some anarchistic troublemaker!'. And to be fair, that might be a legitimate concern.

On the other hand, an employer might think 'Oh great, this guy is conscientious and thorough, thinks outside the box, he's be a valuable addition to the team'.

Potentially - there will be employers who don't want this, 'We don't someone who's going to be all thinking about security and holding things up, just get the job done!'.

The question you need to ask yourself is, what kind of employer do you want to work for? Do you want to work for an employer that appreciates exploit discovery? If so, put it on your CV, because it can only help you find the job that will fit you.

Especially if the jobs you're going for are in web development, there's probably not many employers who *wouldn't* want employees who are thinking about exploits.